# Simplest way to get 3D visualization using 3D keypoints and edges

Tags: blender, graph-visualization, mediapipe

[image]

I have a set of 3D (x,y,z) co-ordinate values of keypoints on a hand. I also have information regarding edges i.e., which keypoints are connected. See figure above for reference. Given this co-ordinate data, I want to know what the simplest way is to visualize this hand in 3D. i.e, I want to be able to see it from different angles by dragging using a mouse.

The above keypoints are from Mediapipe [Hands](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/docs/solutions/hands.md). Their tool only provides a 2d figure plot that you can see. I want a 3D visualization that allows me to see it from all angles.